# State set to 0 after parent::publish

Tags: development, controller, task

I'm extending my controller's publishing method for a task called "setup".

This is the extended method:

```
/**
 * publish function.
 * 
 * @access public
 * @return void
 */
public function publish()
{
    $app      = JFactory::getApplication();
    $jinput   = JFactory::getApplication()->input;
    $ids      = $jinput->get('cid', '', 'array');
    $task     = $this->getTask();
    $date     = JFactory::getDate();            

    $modelitem  = $this->getModel('Item');
    $tableitem  = JTable::getInstance('Item','BestiaTable');      

    foreach($ids as $id)
    {
        $tableitem->load($id);

        switch($task)
        {
            case 'publish'  : $tableitem->autorenew = 1;  
                              break;    

            case 'unpublish': $tableitem->autorenew = 1;
                              break;

            case 'archive'  : $tableitem->autorenew    = 0;
                              $tableitem->terminatedon = $date->toSql();     
                              break;

            case 'trash'    : $tableitem->autorenew    = 0;
                              $tableitem->terminatedon = $date->toSql();
                              $tableitem->end          = $date->toSql();
                              $tableitem->overwriteend = 1;

            case 'setup'    : $SetupHelper             = SetupHelper::getInstance();
                              $setupitem               = $SetupHelper->setupItem($id);
                              if ($setupitem)
                              {

                              }
                              else
                              {
                                  $app->enqueueMessage(implode(", ", $SetupHelper->getErrors()), 'warning');          
                              }
                              break;
            break;
        }

        $tableitem->store();            
    }

    $publish = parent::publish();
    $this->setRedirect('index.php?option=com_bestia&view=items', false);

    return true;
}
```

Okay - publishing and unpublishing works fine, but the setup-task which is started by a toolbar-button like this:

```
JToolbarHelper::custom('items.setup', 'cogs', '', 'Setup item', true);
```

Always changes the item's state to `0` instead of `-1` (which is the state for "wait for setup" or `1` (which is the state for "setup okay").

How can I change this behavior and tell the method which state to use?

Comment: Just to let you know, you're missing a `break;` at the end of `case 'trash'`, and you have 2 `break;`'s at the end of `case 'setup'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are calling `parent::publish()`. This method has an array which maps tasks to states ([line 190](https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/blob/staging/libraries/legacy/controller/admin.php#L190)):

```
$data = array('publish' => 1, 'unpublish' => 0, 'archive' => 2, 'trash' => -2, 'report' => -3);
```

Then it gets the task (next line):

```
$task = $this->getTask();
```

Which is "setup" in your case.
After that it tries to read the value of the task in the array:

```
$value = JArrayHelper::getValue($data, $task, 0, 'int');
```

But it won't find "setup" in that array. So the value is 0. That explains why your state changes to 0.

I wouldn't call parent::publish() if your task is "setup". You could avoid that if you wrap that call like this:

```
 if($task != "setup")
 {
     $publish                             =   parent::publish();
 }
 else
 {
    // Check the code from JControllerAdmin how to set models state 
    // e.g. $modelitem->publish($id, -1); set a nice message and how to redirect
    // back to your list
 }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot - but if I use 

`$modelitem->publish($id, -1);

...

if($task != 'setup')
  {
   $publish        = parent::publish();
  }
`
The state does not change to -1 :-(

Comment: If the publish with -1 doesn't work probably have to write your own database query which updates the state. With default publish method from JModelAdmin it should work but I don't know if you overwrite something from there. The query is not too complicated. If you have problems, open a new question please.